# Optimizing Max Value query

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, time, statistics

I wanted to ask for advice on how I could optimize my query? I hope to make it run faster as I feel it takes away from the UX with the speed.

My program collects data every hour and I want to optimize my query which takes the latest data and creates the top 100 people for a specific event,

```
SELECT a.user_id as user, nickname, value, s.created_on 
FROM stats s,accounts a 
WHERE a.user_id = s.user_id AND event_id = 1 AND s.created_on in  
(SELECT created_on FROM stats WHERE created_on >= NOW() - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) 
ORDER BY value desc 
LIMIT 100
```

The query I have returns the top 100 from the last hour for event_id = 1 but I wish to optimize it and I believe the subquery is the root cause of the problem. I've tried other queries but they end up with either duplicates or the result is not from the latest dataset

Thank you

EDIT::

The table account contains [user_id, nickname]

the stats table contains [user_id, event_id, value, created_on]

Comment: It would help to know which table `event_id` and `value` are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW() - '1 hour'::INTERVAL` in not MySQL syntax; perhaps you meant `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`?

`IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes very poorly.

Not knowing the relationship between `accounts` and `stats` (1:1, 1:many, etc), I can only guess at what might work:

```
SELECT  a.user_id as user, nickname, value, s.created_on
    FROM  stats s,accounts a
    WHERE  a.user_id = s.user_id
      AND  event_id = 1
      AND  s.created_on >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    ORDER BY  value desc
    LIMIT  100
INDEX(event_id, value) -- if they are both in `a`
INDEX(user_id, created_on)
```

or...

```
SELECT  user_id as user, nickname, value,
        ( SELECT MAX(created_on) FROM stats
                WHERE  user_id = a.user_id )  AS created_on
    FROM  accounts
      AND  event_id = 1
      AND  EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  stats
            WHERE  created_on >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
              AND  user_id = a.user_id
      )
    ORDER BY  value desc
    LIMIT  100 
INDEX(user_id, created_on)
INDEX(event_id, value)
```

Please provide

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` for any reasonable candidates

Comment: Sorry, I can't believe I mislabeled this is on postgres! The relationship would be 1:many and the only index that exists would be stats.user_id

Comment: Just tried your first query and it works fantastic, huge improvement! :D thank you